# Average case complexity and Big-O

Tags: time-complexity, average-case

In this [Wikipedia article on Average-case complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity#Sorting_algorithms) there is the text:

> For example, many sorting algorithms which utilize randomness, such as Quicksort, have a worst-case running time of $O(n^2)$, but an average-case running time of $O(n \log(n))$, where n is the length of the input to be sorted.

My question is about the use of $O$ as our function for analyzing the average-case scenario.  My understanding of $O$ is, essentially, $\leq$, which seems like an odd choice to use for average time, which could be much more tightly defined (perhaps like $\Theta$?).

Is Wikipedia correct to use $O$ here, and if so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia use is correct. The notation $O(\cdot)$ denotes a set of function, in particular $O(f(n))$ contains all functions $g(n)$ for which there is a constant $c$  and a choice of $n_0$ such that $g(n) \le c f(n)$ for all $n \ge n_0$.

The average running time of an algorithm is some function of its input size $n$. Therefore it is perfectly correct to say that a function belongs to a set of functions.

Notice also that if $g(n) \in \Theta(f(n))$ then $g(n) \in O(f(n))$.

Comment: I guess my question is, sure it's *technically correct*, it's part of that set, but average time can be much more tightly defined, so why would we go with O, which is *technically correct* for an infinite number of answers.  Since we (presumably) have more tightly bound functions available to us, wouldn't one of them be a more appropriate choice?  (BTW, just to give a flavor to any response you write, it took me several minutes to understand the answer you wrote -- I don't have a very rich background here, so any efforts you take to keep your responses easy to understand are def. appreciated!)

Comment: You can definitely replace the $O(\cdot)$ notation with the $\Theta(\cdot)$ notation in the Wikipedia sentence while keeping it true and also making it more precise. The $O(n \log n)$ part doesn't really bother me but $O(n^2)$ does. The message the sentence is trying to convey is "while the worst case complexity is quadratic, randomization lowers the average complexity to  $n\log n$". I would hence expect a lower-bound on the worst-case complexity (either $\Omega(\cdot)$ or $\Theta(\cdot)$, but not $O(\cdot)$) and an upper bound on the average complexity (either $O(\cdot)$ or $\Theta(\cdot)$)